# Java parsing JSON into floats

Tags: java, json, string, floating-point

I have the following json string:

```
String json = {"z":4.78944,"y":-0.07604187,"x":11.841576};
```

I would like to parse it and create:

```
float x = 4.78944;
float y = -0.07604187;
float z = 11.841576;
```

How can I accomplish this in Java with the input variable `String json`?

Comment: first of all, that string assignment won't compile. Secondly, have you made any effort to research some of the more common json parsing libraries like Gson and Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an Object Model oriented deserialization, take a look at Google-Gson [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Create a model **Coordonate.java**:

```
public class Coordonate {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;

    public float getX() { return x; }
    public float getY() { return y; }
    public float getZ() { return z; }
}
```

Deserialize your JSON string:

```
String json = "{\"z\":4.78944,\"y\":-0.07604187,\"x\":11.841576}";
Coordonate cord = new Gson().fromJson(json, Coordonate.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONObject: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Thereafter, use the getDouble function to access the double value of the keys x, y and z.

Comment: Does this seem right? `float x = (float) json.getDouble("x");` It compiles, not sure if it will work.

Comment: It should. I have used JSONObject before to de-serialize a valid JSON string and then access attributes within.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a more powerful library than just the reference implementation and [use Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Look at [this about how to use it in your usecase.](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_132.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vivec's answer using: 
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Although there is no `getFloat()` on JSONObject getting it as a string and parsing it into float worked fine for me.:

```
Float.parseFloat(myJsonObject.getString("x"));
```